# Terminal shortcuts not working on remote machine

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, bash, ssh

I know this is some kind of setting issue but I can't remember how to resolve it. Basically I'm SSH'ing into a remote machine (Ubuntu) and short cuts such as up, history, tab etc. do not work.

Can anyone tell me what I need to change either on my machine (Mac) or remotely so everything works!

Comment: What is the shell of the Ubuntu machine?

Comment: I'm assuming its bash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash comes with completion and history enabled by default. See your `~/.bashrc` and`/etc/bash.bashrc`. The Ubuntu machine might be using `/bin/sh` instead of `/bin/bash`. `$ chsh -s /bin/bash` should do the trick.